# Disable and Enable drop down using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How I can make my drop down disable in Edit but enable in Create User. I have the drop down in MVC view and Create and Edit user in jquery.  I already tried these but not making it disabled using any of these in jquery:

```
 $("#dropdown").prop("disabled", false);  

 $('#dropDownId').attr('disabled', true);

 $('#dropdown').prop('disabled', true);
```

and in my MVC with when I have like this:

```
  <select id="organization" class="create-user-select-half" disabled>
```

it making it disabled but I can not again Enable it in jquery.

Comment: Your id is `organization`, not `dropdown` or `dropDownId`.  `$('#organization').attr('disabled', true);`

Comment: $(#organization).prop('disabled', true)

Comment: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-disable-enable-a-form-element/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to set

```
$("#dropdown").prop('disabled', true);
```

for disabling a control. To enable it again you have to call:

```
$("#dropdown").prop('disabled', false);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="organization" class="create-user-select-half" disabled>
  <option value="1">dsdsd</option>
  </select>

<button onclick="$('#organization').prop('disabled', false)">Enable</button>
<button onclick="$('#organization').prop('disabled',true)">Disable</button>
```

Comment: the remove is not working. so it is disabled in Create user as well.

Comment: Please check your jQuery selectors. Just added a fiddle.

Comment: it is working here, but maybe because I am enable and disable in the Modal it is different and I am missing  something..

Comment: Please check the id of the dropdown and the selector in your jQuery script. **id="organization"** => **$('#organization')**

Comment: yes, it is correct, it make it disable but when I open the modal that is making is enable is not working.

Comment: I'm sorry, but then we need more info eg. the script for opening your modal. Have you checked the JS console in your browser? Are there any errors? Have you tried to execute `$('#organization').removeAttr('disabled')` in the Browsers JS Console?

Answer (score 1):

you should remove the attribute all together in order to re-enable the dropdown.

`$('#dropdown').removeAttr('disabled')`

Answer (score 0):

To enable all the child elements in a drop-down list:

`for (var x = 0; x < $("#organization")[0].childElementCount; x++) {
                                $('#organization')[0][x].disabled = false;
                            }`

Answer (score 0):

a disabled item is un-clickable. you can use a div outside of your select tag.

```
<div class="editable">
      <select id="organization" class="create-user-select-half" disabled>
</div>

$(".editable").on("click", function () {
    $('#organization').prop('disabled', false)
});
```